# Regular expression javascript and match result

Tags: javascript, regex

I am getting 2 different formats which matches my regular expression.

```
matches = ['10 am', '5 pm', 'by appointment only']
```

or

```
['By Appointment :', '10 am', '8 pm' ]
```

So in first case, the result should be

> '10 am to 5 pm by appointment only'

For second case, the result should be

> 'By Appointment : 10 am to 5 pm'

I tried with below code after joining with 'to'

```
let value = matches.join(' to ');
```

After joining, this would give text as:

> **'10 am to 5 pm to by appointment only'**

or

> **'By Appointment : to 10 am to 8 pm'**

```
if (value.includes('to by appointment only')) {
    value = value.replace('to by appointment only', 'by appointment only');
}
if (value.includes('By Appointment: to')) {
    value = value.replace('By Appointment: to', 'By Appointment:');
}
```

Basically here I am trying to remove unwanted 'to' text after joining
how can I refactor it in better way with the help of regular expression to achieve the same result?

Comment: It seems you are using quote-formatting for code. Can you edit and use the correct formatting? 
Also, you have tagged this with `regex`, but there is no regex in your question.

Comment: I see you are saving edits every 20 seconds. Hint: you can preview what your edit looks like. Take your time, and check the preview before submitting.

Comment: @trincot I am not quite sure how to use the correct formatting in stackoverflow. I am using the block quote for formattting.

Comment: I tried to reformat your question. Have a look at how it was done, and update where you still think it is needed.

Comment: @trincot   The regex is returning array with above formats. So I just need to refactor the code which replaces 'to' text.

Comment: Since you provide only the arrays of the match, the `regex` tag is not relevant and should be removed. However, if you would add the regex part of your code, it is likely we could post a more comprehensive answer that would also impact the regex.

Comment: I did not understand the fact that when joining you are using delimiter `to` and again you are removing the `to` you can use empty as join delimiter

Comment: @rubyist I added an answer. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve it by iterating the `matches` array and append the `to` string if the item ends with `am`. You can check that with the help of [`String.endsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

Live Demo **:**

```js
const matches = ['10 am', '5 pm', 'by appointment only'];

matches.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (item.endsWith('am')) {
    matches[index] = item + ' to '
  }
});

console.log(matches.join(''));
```